# Make it sound like outdoors

Tags: audio-recording

How do I make it sound like it's outdoors? If I record clean audio indoors with no reverb. Obviously, add ambient noise, I'm just talking about the vocals.

Edit: Like this

Thank you

p.s. I have adobe audition

Comment: I upvoted your question because it's a good topic for this forum on sound design, but your link is really unclear.

Comment: I don't want to post this as a separate answer, but [Altiverb](https://www.audioease.com/altiverb/) (very expensive;) can manufacture convolution reverbs even from just the snap of a clapperboard - & also comes with hundreds of pre-recorded impulses.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is valid but I do not understand your embedded link at all. In that example I hear a pretty clean voiceover and lots of city noise. Are you asking how to make the person sound like he's outside?

There's are a few threads that already address this issue, such as:

[Reverbs for Urban Exteriors](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/reverbs-for-urban-exteriors)

[Dialogue Premix - Exterior Verb](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/12662/dialogue-premix-exterior-verb)

[Outdoor Reverb/Delay?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/17283/outdoor-reverb-delay)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I am new to sound design. Usually, if you put city noise on to clear audio it can just sound unconvincing. In the example, it sounds like he's got a good microphone and stood outside to get the type of reverb and sound that is different to a studio, for all I know he could have but I just wanted to know how I could do that with clean audio recorded indoors? Also thanks I'll check those links out.

Comment: Understood. Have a look at the links I referenced, I think they'll be of some help. For your particular example, I think all you need to do is work with some EQ.